# Android Java:Google GDPR check freezes for non-EU users

Tags: java, android

We receive a number of complains from US and UK users(and sometimes from Australian too).They can't start the app as it freezes at startup.Investigation revealed it freezes on following check:

```
ConsentInformation consentInformation = ConsentInformation.getInstance(context);
    String[] publisherIds = {context.getText(R.string.admob_pubId).toString()};
    consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(publisherIds, new ConsentInfoUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConsentInfoUpdated(ConsentStatus consentStatus) {
            // User's consent status successfully updated.
            // check if gdpr consent is required
            boolean showConsent=ConsentInformation.getInstance(context).isRequestLocationInEeaOrUnknown();
        }
}
```

`onConsentInfoUpdated` is never called.
Interesting that sometimes users able to go through this check and start the app.
Does anyone observe similar behavior?